# module 'PyPDF2' has no attribute 'PdfFileReader'

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I am following along the book "Automate Boring Stuff with Python", but I receive the an error when trying to run this simple script.

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('meetingminutes.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
```

The complete error message was:

```
runfile('D:/Python files/PyPDF2/PyPDF2.py', wdir='D:/Python files/PyPDF2')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-caab1b8716b0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Python files/PyPDF2/PyPDF2.py', wdir='D:/Python files/PyPDF2')

  File "C:\Users\cjwu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\cjwu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Python files/PyPDF2/PyPDF2.py", line 22, in <module>
    import PyPDF2

  File "D:\Python files\PyPDF2\PyPDF2.py", line 25, in <module>
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

AttributeError: module 'PyPDF2' has no attribute 'PdfFileReader'
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this:

> runfile('D:/Python files/PyPDF2/PyPDF2.py', wdir='D:/Python files/PyPDF2')

It seems you named your file as **PyPDF2.py**, which is the same name as the **PyPDF2** package. Do not do this because that will conflict with the imports from the actual **PyPDF2** package.

From the [Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) docs:

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the
>   variable [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).
>   ...
>   The directory containing the script being run is placed at the
>   beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This
>   means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules
>   of the same name in the library directory.

So when you do:

```
import PyPDF2
PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
```

The `import` command will look for `PdfFileReader` from *your* **PyPDF2.py** because it imported *your* **PyPDF2.py** instead of the actual **PyPDF2** package. You can check it by printing `PyPDF2.__file__` after `import`ing, which should show the path to the current script.

Simply name your file to something else.
Example:

> PyPDF2.py **-->** mypdfapp.py

Actually, I would also recommend renaming the parent folder (which is also **PyPDF2**).
Example:

> D:/Python files/PyPDF2/PyPDF2.py **-->** D:/Python files/project01/mypdfapp.py

Comment: @BlueGold71 I forgot to mention that a quick way to check the import, is to `print` the imported module's `__file__` attribute, as in `print(PyPDF2.__file__)` after `import`ing, which would show that you were importing the current script.

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
pages = reader.pages
text = "".join([page.extractText() for page in pages])
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**